# Error qtconsole after updating Spyder to 4.0

Tags: spyder, qtconsole

I have a problem with recent Spider's update:

> You have missing dependencies, qt console >= 4.6.0: 4.5.2 (NOK).

This error appears every time I running program and during using i have problems with inputs.

I tried reinstall spyder, update spyder, update this qtconsole, update all and nothing.

See also the [complete error window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzSji.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To avoid this error you need to update qtconsole to its latest version, either with conda (if you use Anaconda) or pip otherwise.

Comment: I have the latest version 4.6.0